# response.text is not a function while building react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build a react-native app with expo and while trying to sign up I get the following error message stemming from my api.js file:

response.text is not a function. (In 'response.text()', 'response.text' is undefined).

Here is my code:

```
const BASE_URL = "my local IP:5000";


export const api = async (url, method, body = null, headers = {}) => {

try {
  const endPoint = BASE_URL.concat(url);
  const reqBody = body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null;

  const fetchParams = {method, headers};

  if((method === "POST" || method === "PUT") && !reqBody) {
      throw new Error("Request body required");
  }

  if(reqBody) {
      fetchParams.headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
      fetchParams.body = reqBody;
  }

  const fetchPromise = fetch(endPoint, fetchParams);
  const timeOutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          reject("Request Timeout");
      }, 3000);
  });

  const response = await Promise.race([fetchPromise, timeOutPromise]);

  return response;
} catch (e) {
  return e;
}
}

export const fetchApi = async (url, method, body, statusCode, token = null, loader = false) 
=> {
try {
    const headers = {}
    const result = {
        token: null,
        success: false,
        responseBody: null
    };
    if(token) {
        headers["x-auth"] = token;
    }

    const response = await api(url, method, body, headers);

    console.log(response);

    if(response.status === statusCode) {
        result.success = true;

        if(response.headers.get("x-auth")) {
            result.token = response.headers.get("x-auth");
        }
```

Here is response.text()

```
        let responseBody;
        const responseText = await response.text();
        //const responseText = await response.json();

        try {
            responseBody = JSON.parse(responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            responseBody = responseText;
        }

        result.responseBody = responseBody;
        return result;

    }
```

Here is response.text()

```
    let errorBody;
    const errorText = await response.text();
    //const errorText = await response.json();

    try {
        errorBody = JSON.parse(errorText);
    } catch (e) {
        errorBody = errorText;
    }

    result.responseBody = errorBody;

    console.log(result);

    throw result;
} catch (error) {
    return error;
}
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the result of `console.log(response);`?

Comment: it seems ```response``` is string ```"Request Timeout"```. Check whether your api request is not timed out

Comment: @DragonWhite Object {
  "isError": true,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isSuccess": false,
}

Comment: I mean your result of `console.log(response);` is object or text?

Comment: @DragonWhite object